# Difference between ctypes' use_errno parameter to shared library classes and function prototypes?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes, errno, function-prototypes

The [shared library classes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) `CDLL`, `OleDLL`, `WinDLL` each take the `use_errno` parameter. So do the [function prototypes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes), `CFUNCTYPE`, `WINFUNCTYPE`. When and to which group do I pass `use_errno=True` and why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue1798) for it's inclusion:

> This patch adds new calling conventions to ctypes foreign functions by
>   passing 'errno=True' or 'GetLastError=True' to the CDLL or WinDLL
>   constructor.
>
> If CDLL(..., errno=True) or WinDLL(..., errno=True) is used, the
>   function objects available in the CDLL or WinDLL instance will set the
>   C global errno to zero before the actual call, and attach the C global
>   errno value after the call as 'errno' attribute to the function
>   object.  This attribute is stored in thread-local storage.

Comment: This doesn't really clear up the difference. I used this feature initially and it doesn't work without also being used on the function prototypes, so the difference is critical to answering this question.